# After starting activity the activity crashes. Textview and string involved

Tags: android, string, textview, spinner

i have a spinner and when you select an item from the spinner a text from a string should show in the textView, (txtdescription1) but when i start the activity it crashes.

i have tested a lot of thing but i dont find a error in the code.

```
Resources res = getResources();
    int[] txt = res.getIntArray(R.array.description);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    txtdescription1.setText(txt[position]);
}
```

Here is the LogCat

```
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.alpha.liveshit/com.alpha.liveshit.Sample}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.alpha.liveshit.Sample.<init>(Sample.java:42)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
12-27 00:37:24.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please show your complete code/Activity

Comment: What's the context of the code? Is it in a static block?

Comment: Show your onCreate() in the activity.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be calling `getResources()` from your activity's constructor. Your activity should not have a constructor (or, at least, not one that interacts with the framework in any way). It hasn't been properly initialized at that point (which is why the call to `getResources()` is throwing a NPE). Put all your initialization code in `onCreate(Bundle)`.